# Is there an microsoft/.net "version" of the Google visualization api

Tags: .net, visualization, data-visualization

This is just an open question on whether  similar type tools/services for visualization available in .Net.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're referring to a library for the Google Visualization API for .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [Microsoft Chart Controls](https://web.archive.org/web/20190502114248/https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=mschart&DownloadId=3633))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for Google Charts API, there's [Google Chart API controls for Asp.NET](http://googlechartnet.codeplex.com/) and [Google Charts for Asp.Net](http://googlecharts.codeplex.com/) on [CodePlex](http://codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are refering to http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source.html, well as it turns out there seems to be pretty nice little library in .net that can transform a System.Data.DataTable into a google JSON datatable, simply exposing this through a webmethod and you can use the google Chart Visualisation!!

This is the library that seems to do the job you'r after for .net: http://code.google.com/p/bortosky-google-visualization/wiki/ReadMe